# Removing [TextRow ] from sql query results

Tags: node.js, geo

So I am working on using a mysql database to hold latitudes and longitudes of locations and the results of my query are coming out as :

`[ TextRow { platitude: '34.19226000', plongitude: '-118.53556100' } ],`

I would like to get rid of the [TextRow ] and simply just have the array that I can store in a variable to pass through a Geolib function.

I am currently storing the latitude and longitude in my database as decimals

```
platitude : {
    type : DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,8),
},
plongitude : {
    type : DataTypes.DECIMAL(11,8)
},
```

My goal is to use the findNeast Geolib function with my query results

this is what I currently have :

```
const query = sequelize.query("SELECT platitude,plongitude FROM peachyPatient.registeredPractices where practiceID ='1'").then(
    function(result){
        const practices = result;

        const location = geolib.findNearest({ latitude: 52.456221, longitude: 12.63128, }, [
            practices,
            { latitude: 51.503333, longitude: -0.119722 },
            { latitude: 55.751667, longitude: 37.617778 },
            { latitude: 48.8583, longitude: 2.2945 },
            { latitude: 59.3275, longitude: 18.0675 },
            { latitude: 59.916911, longitude: 10.727567 },
            // { latitude: 52.516272, longitude: 13.377722 },
           
        ]); console.log(location);
    }
    );
```

When I console.log location, It simply just returns my query results.

this is what the geoLib function looks like in the documentation

```
geolib.findNearest({ latitude: 52.456221, longitude: 12.63128 }, [
    { latitude: 52.516272, longitude: 13.377722 },
    { latitude: 51.515, longitude: 7.453619 },
    { latitude: 51.503333, longitude: -0.119722 },
    { latitude: 55.751667, longitude: 37.617778 },
    { latitude: 48.8583, longitude: 2.2945 },
    { latitude: 59.3275, longitude: 18.0675 },
    { latitude: 59.916911, longitude: 10.727567 },
]);
```

Any help on how to clear this up would be appreciated.

Comment: The TextRow label is the name of the js class. While it prints out in console, it shouldn't be a problem. What's the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

try this: It should return plain json array of object without TextRow.

```
var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
```